# Unable to create zip file using python 3

Tags: python-3.5, zip

zip file creation works fine with python2 when i run same code for python 3 created zip file is not a proper zip (i.e when i do unzip storage_aligned.zip) it throws error as

```
Archive:  storage_aligned.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of storage_aligned.zip or
        storage_aligned.zip.zip, and cannot find storage_aligned.zip.ZIP, period
```

Code Snippet:

```
aligned_zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'w')

for zinfo in self.filelist:
        zef_file = self.fp
        zef_file.seek(zinfo.header_offset, 0)
        fheader = zef_file.read(zipfile.sizeFileHeader)
        if fheader[0:4] != zipfile.stringFileHeader:
            raise BadZipfile("Bad magic number for file header")
        fheader = struct.unpack(zipfile.structFileHeader, fheader)
        fname = zef_file.read(fheader[zipfile._FH_FILENAME_LENGTH])
        if fheader[zipfile._FH_EXTRA_FIELD_LENGTH]:
            zef_file.read(fheader[zipfile._FH_EXTRA_FIELD_LENGTH])

        if fname.decode('utf-8') != zinfo.orig_filename:
            raise zipfile.BadZipfile('File name in directory "%s" and header "%s" differ.' % (
                zinfo.orig_filename, fname))

        # For the first entry, prepend some extraneous bytes before the LFH.  This
        # is acceptable since ZIP implementations use the CD (end of the file) to
        # find entries.  Therefore these bytes are ignored
        if padding_index == 0:
            if sys.version[:1] == '2':
                aligned_zf.fp.write(bytes("\0"*paddings[padding_index]))
            elif sys.version[:1] == '3':
                aligned_zf.fp.write(bytes("\0"*paddings[padding_index], 'utf-8') )
            padding_index += 1

        # if required, add padding after the file data.  This is acceptable as the CD
        # references offsets to the LFHs.  Therefore extraneous data is ignored and not processed
        # orig: aligned_zf.writestr(zinfo, self.read(fname)+'\0'*paddings[padding_index])
        aligned_zf.writestr(zinfo, self.read(fname.decode('utf-8')))
        if sys.version[:1] == '2':
            aligned_zf.fp.write('\0'*paddings[padding_index])
        elif sys.version[:1] == '3':
            aligned_zf.fp.write(bytes('\0'*paddings[padding_index], 'utf-8'))

        padding_index+=1

    aligned_zf.close()
```

Comment: Please guide what is the missing part for python3 in above code snippet.

Comment: Also, what library are you using for making the zip file? Could be possible that it has changed from Python2 to Python3. Does Python give any log messages?

Comment: @ytpillai:    below is the error,
    zf = ZipAlignFile(args.output, mode='r')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/packagetools-3.2.9-py3.5.egg/packagetools/zipalign.py", line 22, in __init__
    zipfile.ZipFile.__init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: in both version zipfile is imported and used for zip file creation.

Comment: zf = ZipAlignFile(args.output, mode='r') 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/packagetools-3.2.9-py3.5.egg/packagetools/zipalign.py", line 22, in init 
zipfile.ZipFile.__init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1026, in init self._RealGetContents() 
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
 raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: @ytpillai:   I see difference while printing zinfo (print("info", zinfo)) between python2 and python3:
In py2:
=> ('info', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x7fb9e0af4c08>)
In py3:

=> info <ZipInfo filename='pad' filemode='-rw-rw-r--' file_size=1>   Please help me understand is this the reason for issue?  or is it just the print difference b/w py2 and py3

Comment: Check your file permissions. What os are you on

Comment: Hi @ytpillai thanks for your response. I have narrow down the issue, it is due to writing the padding bytes in python3 aligned_zf.fp.write(bytes("\0"*paddings[padding_index])),  can you please tell if there is alternate method to write bytes into zip file?  When i comment the line where writing the paddings to zip file, the zip file created in python3 also looks valid.

Comment: I am able to overcome this issue.  It looks in python3 writing the bytes directly to the zip file is not possible.  aligned_zf.fp.write(bytes("\0"*paddings[padding_index])),  I changed to write the padding as a new file.  Thanks @ytpillai

Comment: Sure, but it might be useful to find out what the difference is in the implementation that causes that. Maybe you found a bug in Python 3

Comment: I understand / believe, python3 doesn't allow to write null bytes to a zip file directly.  Instead it requires to zip everything as a file or data with zinfo.  In my code snippet of question "aligned_zf.fp.write", directly tries to write the null bytes for padding directly to the zip file which is restricted in python3.

Comment: Lmao OK so maybe the changed the way they read zipfiles hten because it doens't look like it actually stops you from writing padded 0s directly from Python. Is this documented at all?

Comment: @ytpillai, sorry for late response, the zip files created by writing the padding bytes directly from python is creating zip file with no error, but when i try to unzip using unzip command or even via python commands it throws error as not valid zip file.